# 2d terrain generation using shader

Tags: opengl, libgdx, fragment-shader, terrain, vertex-shader

I am trying to render a random terrain using shader scripts

## Create function..

```
tex = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ground.png"));
top = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("top.png"));
ShaderProgram.pedantic = false;
shader = new ShaderProgram(VERT, FRAG);
shader.begin();
shader.setUniformi("u_top", 1);
shader.end();
top.bind(1);
Gdx.gl.glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE0);
batch = new SpriteBatch(1000, shader);
batch.setShader(shader);
```

## Render function

```
batch.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    batch.draw(tex, i * 256 * Initiate.getScale(), 0,
                        256 * Initiate.getScale(), 256 * Initiate.getScale());
batch.end();
```

## Vertex shader

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main()
{
    vTexCoord = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position =  u_projTrans * a_position;
}
```

## Fragment shader

```
#ifdef GL_ES
#define LOWP lowp
precision mediump float;
#else
#define LOWP 
#endif

varying LOWP vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

uniform sampler2D u_texture1;
uniform sampler2D u_texture2;



 void main() 
    vec4 texColor ;
//calculate top vertex 
    float clamp = 0.5 + slope*(sin(vTexCoord0.x*mfrq)/mfrq+sin(vTexCoord0.x*frq)/frq+sin(vTexCoord0.x*nfrq)/nfrq);
//if larger the draw texture
    if(vTexCoord0.y > clamp){
      texColor = texture2D(u_texture1, vTexCoord1);
    }


 // else map coordinate for top texture and draw 
        else{
        float tempy = 16.0*(vTexCoord0.y + 0.0625- clamp);
        texColor = texture2D(u_texture2, vec2 (vTexCoord1.x,tempy));
        }
        gl_FragColor = texColor;
```

## Output

[image]

## So the question is..

- How do a add a texture at the top of this terrain?
- Is there any simple way of redering such a terrain?

Comment: Where are your `#version` directives?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in fragment shader by calculating two parameters - distance along the terrain surface, and depth perpendicular to surface, this can be done through attributes or calculated in vertex shader, depending on how you generate you terrain, then just sample your texture based on those two coordinates, with tiling along the first coordinate.

Distance along the surface is just a sum lengths of edges that form surface.
Depth can be calculated as distance from vertex to surface edge, and interpolation will give you approximate depth in the whole polygon. Quads should give you better interpolation then triangles.

Comment: thanks for replying buddy but im new to shader language
and didnt understand what you said 
will you please elaborate what you said
or guide me to somewhere (site) so that i was able to gaher enough knowledge to understand that

Comment: @bindassdost what you have to understand here is basics of geometry and linear algebra, and a schema how rendering pipeline works, then details how to implement this would be trivial to find out. 

Can you elaborate what exactly you did not understand, then I'll add details you need.

Comment: basically "how to use interpolation" .I thought i could update gl_position in vertex shader according to sine and draw my texture simply in fragment shader

Comment: @bindassdost interpolation works automatically: you set out variable values in vertex shader and interpolated values are put into corresponding input variables in fragment shader.

Comment: i am now able to add a texture at top but it gave me very low fps (30-33 without any music and box2d) and (10-14) with box2d and music
i know this is because there is too much calculation in fragment shader

from past few days i had tried (compressed image format etc1 , used step function instead of if but not much improvement in fps)

will you please help me optimize my vertex shader cause im unable to do that 
im using libgdx

Comment: @bindassdost it looks like this is not a whole picture, I assume that xfrq are constant for the shaders, so you can interpolate vTexCoord0.x*xfrq instead of texcoor and get rid of additional multiplication, also you can precalc 1/xfrq and replace division with multiplication which is generally faster.

Comment: @bindassdost also you using some very convoluted way to calc clamp, can you describe what you do?.

Comment: "0.5" is to start from the mid "slope" slope is to smoothen the clip(discontinute when freq changes from one to other)

rest is mfrq (1 or 2) for main slope and frq and nfrq to random it
i divide every sine with freq as amp is inverse to freq for smootheness

Comment: i can calculate all this is my app to generate a set off points that difines my terrain

.BUT i dont know how to fill the area below that with texture in shader

.You said i can interpolate vTexCoord0.x*xfrq instead of texcoord
(all frq are set by main thread as uniforms )
how to interpolate that ??

and thanx for replying